# PHP convert html special chars like accents to show properly

Tags: php, html-entities

I have a simple web page where I get some data from $_POST that users input: comments, usernames, etc. And I send them to email and save them on database. My problem is what when I send to email, doesn't matter what client is, I only see gibberish. I tried declaring the meta tag in the emails with all iso 88xx, utf8, windows, etc., but with no success. Also tried a million examples of htmlentities(), all leading to the same thing... plain gibberish. (Althought the source code shows different things sometimes, the plain text never changes).

Example code:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
   $name = htmlentities($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

A result of mail() of $name (Don Quijóte) would be something like this "Don QuijÃ³te".

Sorry if this is a repost but I just can't get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the headers, something like...

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:plain/text;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

This sets the encoding to UTF-8. More here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

It is surprisingly hard to send a mail in the right way. The error you get with Don Quijote is due to the fact that your string is in utf8 but it is showed with ISO8859 encoding. (That is why you get that weird A and a small 3.

I would recomend using php mailer [You can get it here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

It is way simpler to setup and it will be more efficient if you at some time in the future need to send out a lot of emails. (Because mail() opens and closes the connection on each call)

Also be aware that if you are using utf-8 everything should be with utf-8. Your database should be set to utf-8. You outputs to html and so on. Every step of the way you should be sure it is utf8.

Comment: I am gonna keep the note about the PHP Mailer, seems like a it will come in handy.